# How do I enable a specific pam config in the lockscreen?

Tags: lightdm, pam

In Trusty, there is a new lockscreen that fits the look and feel of lightdm, and shares some config files, especially for pam.

I am using `libpam-fprintd` to allow using my fingerprint reader when asked for a sudo password, or for unlocking the screen.

The point is that I don't want to allow the fingerprint reader when logging into the desktop. But I want to allow it when unlocking the screen. The reason for that is that fingerprint won't allow to open the gnome-keyring, which is fine when unlocking, but not when loging-in. This also enables me to have a strong password, as I type it only once, then use the fingerprint reader.

See [the PPA page instructions](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint), especially the "Note on keyrings and passwordless logins" part

Before the new lock-screen, `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` was used by the greeter, not by the (old) lock-screen. So I had a different behaviour when logging in and when unlocking, which was exactly what I wanted.

See [this page from the Thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_enable_integrated_fingerprint_reader_with_fprint) for the config used.

Now, it seems that `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` is used by both the greeter and the lock-screen.

So my need would be to have a distinct pam config file for the greeter and for the lock screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. From the Unity code (lockscreen/UserAuthenticatorPam.cpp):

```
// FIXME (andy) We should install our own unityshell pam file.
  return pam_start("lightdm", username_.c_str(),
                   &conversation, &pam_handle_) == PAM_SUCCESS;
```

You should file a feature request for this.

Comment: Should this perhaps be filed as a bug feature request then?

Comment: Opened bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/1305440

Comment: Bug has been fixed in trusty proposed, please help to verify the fix.